# Rigid body неправильно применяется для ходовой танка

Tags: blender

Анимировал передвижение танка с помощью rigid body по уроку с youtube. После падения на землю катки начинают вращаться во все стороны, хотя они никак не пересекаются. В самом уроке автор в качестве примера использует танк с катками, расположенными в ряд, а в качестве collision shape использует цилиндр, но у моей модели катки расположены в шахматном порядке, и если я выберу цилиндр, то они пересекутся и начнут "чудить" ещё до падения на землю. Поэтому в качестве collusion shape для пустышки, заменяющей модель катка, я выбрал mesh.

После падения - катки вращаются во все стороны
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
До падения

Answer (score 0):

Вроде что-то начало прояснятся - распределил разные катки по коллекциям, и они работают получше.